# php include from file loader object no keeping variable

Tags: php, object

First I will explain what I'm trying to do, I'm working on a php router for experimenting on how they work and in a object I'm instanciating the router object and I can create routes no problem there.

Now I'm trying something a bit more complicated, I want to be able to load routes from files included from a folder named routes where I won't know in advance the files name. Still no problem there, pretty simple.

Doing my inclusion, I thought, why leave the include inside the object, I should create à fileLoader object that will be dedicated to recursively load the files from a folder. I did it, and made a new object.

Now when calling my loader object, the $router variable that should be set, isn't and I can't create routes because of undefined variable. A bit of code for explanation.

This is the function that call the router object:

```
private function projectRooting(){

        $router = new Router\Router($this->baseUri);

        $fileLoader = new FileLoader();
        $fileLoader -> loadFolder($this->fullDirName, "/routes");

        // include_once($this->fullDirName."/routes/web.php");

        $router->run();
    }
```

This is the function from the fileLoader:

```
public function loadFolder(string $path, string $directory){
        $theDirectory = $path. "/" .$directory;
        $files = scandir($theDirectory);

        foreach($files as $file){
            if(is_file($theDirectory. "/" .$file))
                include_once($theDirectory. "/" .$file);
            else{
                if($file != "." && $file != "..")
                    $this->loadFolder($path, $directory. "/" .$file);
            }
        }
    }
```

A route example from the include file:

```
$router->get("/", function(){echo "Welcome on the home page!";});
```

Now with the uncommented code, it won't work, but if I comment the $fileLoader part and uncomment the include_once, everything goes on again.

Have I missed something in the way include works when called from another object?

Thanks in advance if you reply, and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: So `$router->run();` seems undefined for you? You get some error?

Comment: Nop, $router->run() works fine. What doesn't work is the $route->get methode that is in another file called by the loadFolder include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are with scope problems, your `$route` variable is not acessible inside the included file. Try use global variables scope:

```
private function projectRooting(){
  global $router;
  $router = new Router\Router($this->baseUri);
  ...
```

Then, inside your included file put it

```
global $router;
$router->get("/", function(){echo "Welcome on the home page!";});
```

It probably must works, now, why the simply include_once works?

The problem is the `loadFolder` function, when you call it the `include_once` inside this function has no reference to `$router` variable, it means if you paste all `loadFolder` content inside `projectRooting` function then it will probably works.

Another way to solve it is to pass `$router` by argument to `loadFolder` function.

Comment: Thanks, I will test that this evening. I thought about passing $router variable to the loadFolder but I want it to be able to load file anywhere (mostly with globals so include works). I think I will test it with global and try something else.

Comment: I tested it with global and it works, so I will take some time to look if I can do it differently.